# vim scripting - build current/main file

Tags: vim

I'm using vim to edit lua scripts (though this has everything to with vim and nothing to do with lua). I've currently mapped

```
:map <F1> :w^M:!lua %^M
```

so that I can hit F1 in the current file to execute it and see any results, before pressing ENTER again to go back to editing.

Sometimes, I'm working with a project with several different files where one is the main file so I'd like to implement the following:

- Pressing `<Control-F1>` stores the name of the current file (%) into a variable, let's call it `mainfile`.
- If `mainfile` is set, then `<F1>` executes `:w^M:!lua ${mainfile}^M`, otherwise it executes the current file (as above).

I've used vim quite a bit before, but not its scripting feature - for example, `:let mainfile = %` seems not to work (invalid expression).

Is there an easy way to do this? I have a feeling, if it's possible it'll be something like 3 lines.

Comment: `:let mainfile=expand("%")` works, see `:h expand()`.

Comment: You can check if a variable is set with an expression like `exists("mainfile")`, see `:h exists()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `mainfile` has been set in the global scope (see `:h global-variable`) something like the following function should do the trick:

```
function! LuaExecMainOrCurrent ()
    execute ":w" expand("%")
    execute ":!lua" exists("g:mainfile") ? g:mainfile : expand("%")
endfunction
```

The [`execute`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/28.html) command (see `:h :execute`) assembles a string and interprets it as another command.

We are using a conditional expression (see `:h expr1`) instead of an [if](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/21.html) (see `:h if`).

We can call the function like this:

```
:call LuaExecMainOrCurrent()
```

Comment: Instead of `expand("%")`, a reference to the special `%` register could have been used (see `:help "%`). Something like `execute ":w" @%`. The `@` is for referencing the value of a register, instead of a variable.